# Referring to class variables as default parameters in PHP function

Tags: php, function, optional-parameters

I would like to have a function in my class that has a default parameter so that one can omit the argument if required. I want the default to be a variable stored in my class;

Hi why is this showing error messages in Aptana?

```
class property{
    private $id;
    function load_data($id = $this->id){
        //...blah blah blah
    }
}
```

Should I instead use

```
class property{
    static $id;
    function load_data($id = self::id){
        //...blah blah blah
    }
}
```

?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't do what you're looking for. Instead you should simply check to see if the argument has a value, and if it doesn't, assign the default value which is the object property.

```
class property{
    private $id;
    function load_data($id = null){
        $id = (is_null($id)) ? $this->id : $id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I do like the ternary, I try to avoid setting a variable to itself.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
class property
{
    private $id;

    function load_data($id = null){

        if (is_null($id)) {
            $id = $this->id;
        }

        //...blah blah blah
    }
}
```

Comment: Not that close, saw the AJAX notice before I hit submit. ;-)

Comment: @JackMahoney: haha, sarcasm? If you found one of our answers acceptable, please accept one.

Comment: @MikePurcell nah it was just funny to see. Accepted answer above but yours is just the same so thanks any way

Comment: @JackMahoney: No problem, important thing is you got your question answered.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question but I came up on it searching for the same kind of thing and the answer is yes you can do it, as long as you define it as a constant:

```
class property{
    const $id;
    function load_data($id = self::id){
        //...blah blah blah
    }
}
```